# What is the equivalent of this Linux command on Windows cmd?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This command sets an environment variable ("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES") for a python script before running.

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 python my_script.py  # Uses GPUs 2 and 3.
```

It works fine on a Linux machine but on Windows, it says that

```
'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Is it possible to do that on Windows without altering the python script?

Comment: What about `set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 & python my_script.py` ?

Comment: did you try `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a one liner simply run on Windows:

```
set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 & python my_script.py
```

Answer (score 4):

For windows, this worked for me too, thanks to Adonis. you have two options

1. on the command line you can use the following command

   > set TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 & python demo\singleperson.py
2. on the main python file, put the following lines, below import things

   ```
    import os

    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"

    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
   ```

then run the python file on the command line

```
python demo\singleperson.py
```